# Property 'fullDocument' does not exist on type 'ChangeStreamDropDocument'

Tags: typescript, mongodb, express

I cloned an express TS project which throws me a Typescript error in a Mongo related function as per title.

```
Property 'fullDocument' does not exist on type 'ChangeStreamDocument<IUser>'.
  Property 'fullDocument' does not exist on type 'ChangeStreamDropDocument'.

52     const id = data.fullDocument?.user_id || ''
```

This project works fine on other machines but the error emerges only on my machine.

I've tried downgrading my TS and node version but the problem presists. I have a feeling it might be a version issue and I really appreciate if someone can point out the error.

These are my current versions typescript@4.5.5, mongoose@6.2.0, @types/mongoose@5.11.97

Comment: Have you tried updating `mongoose` and/or `@types/mongoose`? Also, on the [npm page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/mongoose) it says the types package is deprecated, so you could try dropping it alltogether.

Answer (score 0):

I downgraded the node version to 16.17.1 and it somehow works.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).